# Read data from table broken into pieces from text file

Tags: python, parsing, text

I'm trying to parse information in a text file that looks like this

```
 Distance (m): 
                1             2             3             4             5 
      1  0.000000D+00
      2  0.753566D+02  0.000000D+00
      3  0.122200D+01  0.718244D+02  0.000000D+00
      4  0.2553551D+00 -0.190505D+01  0.835309D+02  0.000000D+00
      5 -0.2153D+01  0.650008D+00 -0.28353736D+01  0.673503D+02  0.000000D+00
      6  0.772331D+02 -0.263367D+01  0.125687D+00 -0.245234204D+01  0.722401D+02
      7  0.1735236D+01 -0.570005D+00  0.241723D+01  0.3224293D+01  0.413630D+02
      8 -0.849551D+00 -0.154230D+01  0.1488443D+02  0.235537D+01  0.961729D+00
      9 -0.180118D+00  0.141798D+00  0.156748D+00  0.153549D+01  0.211804D-01
     10  0.20363676D+00 -0.990433D-01  0.160539D+00  0.231715D+00  0.142838D+01
           6             7             8             9            10 
      6  0.000000D+00
      7  0.203361D+01  0.000000D+00
      8 -0.502446D+00  0.141591D+00  0.000000D+00
      9 -0.9242897D-01  0.403504D+02  0.104142D+00  0.000000D+00
     10 -0.744021D-02  0.122414D+02 -0.224381D-01  0.245097D+02  0.000000D+00
  End
```

I've tried this but is giving something completly unformatted.

```
table = []
capture_data = False

with open('distance_data.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()

        if capture_data:
            values = line.split()
            
            if not values:
                break

            values = [value.replace('D', 'E') for value in values]

            try:
                values = [float(value) for value in values]
                table.append(values)
            except ValueError:
                break
        elif "Distance (m)" in line:
            capture_data = True

for row in table:
    print(row)
```

I want to have a nicely formatted list/array, maybe a dictionary, depending on what is more convenient. The table should look something like this

```
  1    2    3  ...  9    10
1 0.0   
2 75.3 0.0 
3 1.2  71.0 0.0
...
9 0.2  0.1  0.2 ... 0.0
10 0.2 -0.1 0.2 ... 24.5  0.0
```

So that after I can print the distance between each point, like `Distance from point 1 to point 10 is 0.2 m`

Comment: [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26937531)

Comment: Do you have column indices separated on different lines? If not, and they are on the same line, update your input to show the actual fragment

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest this is the actual way the column appears. When it has more than 5 points, the text file is broken into columns of a maximum of 5.

Comment: @001 sorry I don't see how I could use tabular for this. I believe the problem here, at this point is parsing the data

Comment: @manuelpb, Why row index is broken: the `10`th row is followed by the `6`th index ?

Comment: It is the way the software outputs the data

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The code outputs the data like this The first column represents the distance between the first point and the other nine points. The second column shows the distance between the second point and the remaining eight points, and so on. After the fifth point, a new line is created, and the table continues with the distances between the sixth and the remaining four points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line with @oszkar's answer, in case you want to print everything

```
distances = {}

with open('distance_data.txt', 'r') as f:
    distance_data = f.readlines()

num_points = 0

for line in distance_data[1:]:
    line_data = line.strip().split()
    if line_data:
        point_number = int(line_data[0])
        if point_number > num_points:
            num_points = point_number

for line in distance_data[1:]:
    line = [float(i.replace('D', 'e')) if 'D' in i else i for i in line.strip().split()]
    key = line[0]
    if key not in distances:
        distances.update({key: line[1:num_points + 1]})
    else:
        distances[key] += line[1:num_points + 1]

def get_distance(p, q):
    return distances[str(max(p, q))][min(p, q) - 1]

for p in range(1, num_points + 1):
    for q in range(1, num_points + 1):
        if p < q:
            distance = get_distance(p, q)
            print(f'Distance {p} to {q} is {distance}')
```

Answer (score 1):

The next code provides a dictionary `distances`, where the keys are the points (row numbers from distance data), the values are the distances (only contains the elements lower triangular distance matrix as in the original input data).

It also contains a function (`get_distance`) to calculate the distance between points (no error handling).

There is also an example at the end to get the distance between given points.

```py
distances = {}

with open('distance_data.txt', 'r') as f:
    distance_data = f.readlines()

for line in distance_data[1:-1]:
    line = [float(i.replace('D', 'e')) if 'D' in i else i for i in line.strip().split()]
    if not set(line) <= set([str(i) for i in list(range(len(distance_data)))]):
        key = line[0]
        if key not in distances:
            distances.update({key: line[1:]})
        else:
            distances[key] += line[1:]

def get_distance(p, q):
    return distances[str(max(p, q))][min(p, q) - 1]

p, q = 6, 8
print(f'The distance from point {p} to point {q} is {get_distance(p, q)}')
```

Comment: Thanks @oszkar. Do you know a way to make it so that when I have more than 10 points still works?

Comment: @manuelpb Changed the code to work with arbitrary number of points. And could you please approve the answer if solves your problem?

Comment: This does not work for me

Comment: @manuelpb I was made the changes without able to try it out. Error corrected, it works.